# How to I prevent Django Admin for overriding the custom widget for a custom field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model field, a form field, and a widget that I am using in an app. The details of the code don't matter. The key is that the field correctly renders in regular forms but is overridden in admin.

Here is some pseudo-code of what the field basically looks like:

```
class SandwichWidget(forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'sandwichfield/widgets/sandwichfield.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None):
        widgets = (
            NumberInput(),
            Select(choices=FILLING_CHOICES),
            NumberInput(),
        )
        super(SandwichWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            value = Sandwich(value)
            return [
                value.top,
                value.middle,
                value.bottom
            ]
        return [None, None, None]


class SandwichFormField(forms.MultiValueField):
    widget = SandwichWidget

    def __init__(self, input_date_formats=None, input_time_formats=None, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.IntegerField(),
            forms.CharField(),
            forms.IntegerField(),
        )
        super(SandwichFormField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)


class SandwichField(models.PositiveIntegerField):

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'IntegerField'

    def formfield(self, *args, **kwargs):
        defaults={'form_class': SandwichFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(SandwichField, self).formfield(*args, **defaults)
```

It apparently happens because of [this line in `django/contrib/admin/options.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.4/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L89) which specifies the override of the `models.IntegerField` should be `widgets.AdminIntegerFieldWidget`. Because `models.PositiveIntegerField` inherits from `models.IntegerField`, and because [line 181](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.4/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L181) loops over all subclasses of the field, it seems like there is no way to prevent the widget from being overridden in admin.

This is a real problem, because I use this custom field, with its custom widget, all over my site and throughout admin, and I do not want to have put in a custom value for `override_fields` every time I want to use the field. Ideally, developers should be able to use the custom field without having to provide a custom admin each time.

Currently I'm inheriting from `forms.PositiveIntegerField` because when stored and retrieved from the database, it is a positive integer, and I want to take advantage of all of the coding already in place for handling positive integer values.

Currently it looks like the *only* solution is changing my field to inherit from `models.Field` and then copying and pasting all of the `PositiveIntegerField` and `IntegerField` functionality from the django code. Is there an alternative to this?

Of course, I can always have my formfield ignore whatever widget is sent to it and always use the custom widget, but this raises a problem when I actively *want* to override the widget, which absolutely could happen. I just don't want admin to override my widget.

Comment: Have you created your own form for your admin class so that it uses the widget you want?

Comment: The code above describes a standalone custom field used by many different applications in this website -- and indeed across a number of other websites I've developed. It also is used by other people. So the solution has to be contained somehow within the custom field itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I added the second line from the bottom to your code):

```
class SandwichField(models.PositiveIntegerField):

    def formfield(self, *args, **kwargs):
        defaults={'form_class': SandwichFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        defaults['widget'] = SandwichFormField.widget
        return super(SandwichField, self).formfield(*args, **defaults)
```

The admin code is passing you a kwargs that has their own widget, so you have
to override it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with [django-pint](https://github.com/CarliJoy/django-pint).

Looking into AdminIntegerFieldWidget I figured that it only overwrites the class, so that the width differ between BigInt and Int.

So I took care that during the creation of the `FormField` only these Widgets are ignored, but only those.

```
class SandwichFormField(forms.MultiValueField):
    def __init__(self, input_date_formats=None, input_time_formats=None, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.IntegerField(),
            forms.CharField(),
            forms.IntegerField(),
        )


        def is_special_admin_widget(widget) -> bool:
            """
            There are some special django admin widgets, defined
            in django/contrib/admin/options.py in the variable
            FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS
            The intention for Integer and BigIntegerField is only to
            define the width.

            They are set through a complicated process of the
            modelform_factory setting formfield_callback to
            ModelForm.formfield_fo_dbfield

            As they will overwrite our Widget we check for them and
            will ignore them, if they are set as attribute.

            We still will allow subclasses, so the end user has still
            the possibility to use this widget.
            """
            WIDGETS_TO_IGNORE = [
                FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS[models.IntegerField],
                FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS[models.BigIntegerField],
            ]
            classes_to_ignore = [
                ignored_widget["widget"].__name__
                for ignored_widget in WIDGETS_TO_IGNORE
            ]
            return getattr(widget, "__name__") in classes_to_ignore

        widget = kwargs.get("widget", None)
        if widget is None or is_special_admin_widget(widget):
            widget = SandwichWidget()
        kwargs["widget"] = widget
        super(SandwichFormField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)
```

This way you can make sure, that you get correct widget in the admin but are still able to overwrite them (with everything but the special admin fields).

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks Kound. @Jordan Reiter this should be accepted as the answer.